# How to make a while loop end with a specific input

Tags: java, while-loop

This is the code I have right now and can't figure out why this while loop isnt ending when there is a period entered.

```
while (emailTxt!="."){
  emailTxt = "";
  emailTxt = scanner.nextLine();
  totalText.add(emailTxt);
}
```

Comment: Wrong way to compare a String. Use the `.equals()` method.

Comment: You should use emailTxt.equals() or emailTxt.contains() to do comparison.

Comment: You should have used `!".".equals(emailTxt)` instead of `!=` operator

Answer (score 2):

emailTxt is a String. A String in Java is considered an Object. You want to use the Object.equals().

So

while(!(emailTxt.equals("."))

Answer (score 0):

You should use `equals()` to compare two string.

```
while (!".".equals(emailTxt)) {
    // ...
}
```